# Buildozer End-of-central-directory signature not found

Tags: android, python, linux, kivy, buildozer

I am new to kivy and buildozer. I have been trying to start off by trying to debug and deploy a sample code on my phone. But I have been getting this error consistently.I have checked and found the zip files in the directory. Please help.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 905, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 902, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 508, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 147, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 190, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 551, in build_recipes
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 550, in prepare_build_dir
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 435, in unpack
  File "/home/shanty/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1427, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/home/shanty/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 774, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/home/shanty/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/shanty/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_9: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/unzip /home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/1.10.0.zip

  STDOUT:
Archive:  /home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/1.10.0.zip


  STDERR:
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/1.10.0.zip or
        /home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/1.10.0.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/1.10.0.zip.ZIP, period.

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/shanty/Documents/k/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```